# Android how to implement creating a 3D Page Folding Animation

Tags: android, animation

I want to implement the animation like the IReader open book animation when I click a book and close book animation, this is IOS can do [Page Folding Animation](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-3d-page-folding-animation-page-sketch-spine-fold-effect--mobile-13473), I want to implement in Android.
Someone tell to use Camera, but I can't work out, if anyone who knows how to work out in Android, please tell me how to do, I will appreciate.

Here is my code:

```
final CubeView01 cubeView01 = (CubeView01) view.findViewById(R.id.cubeview01);  // cover layer
final ScaleView scaleView = (ScaleView) view.findViewById(R.id.scaleview); // content layer
cubeView01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // cover layer scaleY
        objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(cubeView01, "scaleY", 1.0F, cubeView01.getHeightRatio());
        objectAnimator.setDuration(duration);
        objectAnimator.start();

        objectAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Float value = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();

                float ratio = (value - 1.0F) / (cubeView01.getHeightRatio() - 1.0F);
                ratio = Math.min(ratio, 1.0F);
                // cover layer scaleX
                cubeView01.setScaleX(value);
                cubeView01.rotate(-((int) (80 * ratio)));

                float valueX = (cubeView01.getWidthRatio() - 1.0F) * ratio + 1.0F;
                float valueY = value;
                scaleView.setScaleX(valueX);
                scaleView.setScaleY(valueY);
            }
        });
    }
});

/**
 * @param degreeY
 */
public void rotate(int degreeY) {
    mCamera.save();
    mCamera.rotateY(degreeY);
    mCamera.getMatrix(mMatrix);
    mCamera.restore();
    mCamera.save();
    postInvalidate();
}
```

Now I make cover layer scaleX, scaleY and rotateY, while content layer scaleX, scaleY. But it is not perfect as ibook; and I don't use translate, if you know how to make better, please give me some suggestion, thank you!

Comment: Please show us what have you done so far? So we can address/help you specifically to the point. This is not site for "I want this and that...". Please show us your effort

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion  , Here is my code now

Answer (score 0):

This is known as Pagecurl animation

There is a very good implementation [here](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl). This can be done using [OPENGLS](https://www.opengl.org/)

Comment: Maybe it is not the effect of I want ,I think  the animation is scale and the Page Fold Animation , if you know more please tell me , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out this cool project. This may help you.
[Page Curl for Android](https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl)

Comment: Sorry, the project is not the effect that I want. I clicked a book in the bookshelf , the animation  will be showing ,the back layer imageview will be scale and the front layer imageview will be flip .